# How to use pushdown predicates in Presto connector

Tags: presto, connector

I would like to extend Presto's `example-http` connector to add the relevant predicates to the REST API call made by the connector to  minimize data transfer.

I have been spending now quite a few hours looking through the documentation, online posts and the presto source code but I can't figure out which calls are involved and how to go about this.

It's being mentioned in so many places, but I cannot find any simple code samples or internal descriptions. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Did you try getting help directly on the `#dev` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html)?

Comment: No, I didn't, but thanks for the suggestion. I'm sure I'll use that int eh future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading the source code and running it in a debugger I found it to be rather straight forward on one hand, while restrictive on the other.

The straight forward part is that we simply have to override `isPushdownFilterSupported` and `pushdownFilter` when implementing the `ConnectorMetadata` interface.

The restrictive part is that the query planner now believes that the connector can deal with any type and combination of table filters. In my case, I would only want to take care of those, the remote API I'm calling is supporting and have Presto take care of the rest.

It appears the Presto team is fully aware of that, as a) the methods are labeled `@Experimental` and b) by the respective comments `This interface can be replaced with a connector optimizer rule once the engine supports these (#12546).` This would be clearly the right approach for my use case.

```
   /**
     * Experimental: if true, the engine will invoke pushdownFilter instead of getTableLayouts.
     *
     * This interface can be replaced with a connector optimizer rule once the engine supports these (#12546).
     */
    @Experimental
    default boolean isPushdownFilterSupported(ConnectorSession session, ConnectorTableHandle tableHandle)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Experimental: returns table layout that encapsulates the given filter.
     *
     * This interface can be replaced with a connector optimizer rule once the engine supports these (#12546).
     */
    @Experimental
    default ConnectorPushdownFilterResult pushdownFilter(ConnectorSession session, ConnectorTableHandle tableHandle, RowExpression filter, Optional<ConnectorTableLayoutHandle> currentLayoutHandle)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Comment: This is specific to Facebook's fork of Presto ([learn more about prestodb vs prestosql](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/380)). I recommend that you check out the Presto SQL 330 release. The API is IMO more sane. It's not "as powerful" yet, but doesn't have any future-compatibility problems involved here. The starting point for pushdown is https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/d36b1053d733cfd6d1c2bf043c7ca321eae93da2/presto-spi/src/main/java/io/prestosql/spi/connector/ConnectorMetadata.java#L708-L725.   Ask [Presto community](https://prestosql.io/slack.html) if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't aware that it had forked. And indeed that API is already more in line with what I would need.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. You can read more at https://prweb.com/releases/prweb16070792.htm, but more importantly -- join the (always growing) community! See you on https://prestosql.io/slack.html